# Microphone detected but not working on Win10

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

I bought a new powerful PC last month with an original Windows 10 licence on it. I got a new microphone from Amazon a couple weeks ago but I can't get it to work.

It goes fine with my smartphone, but doesn't receive anything with the PC.

As you can see from the picture (sorry for the Italian) the microphone is recognized, and when I connect the audio jack/plug some lines of the audio level become green, but then it stay at zero with all the lines in grey:

[image: Registration devices].

I checked various suggestions, like checking if the microphone is the default registration device, if the receiving volume is not 0% (it is at 100%), drivers to reinstall and similar stuff.. Being a brand new PC I've used for so little time I'm pretty sure I didn't change any strange/important stuff from the default ones.

I have no more ideas to try, can anybody help me?